# Is there a way to split m:n relations in a pandas dataframe to get bi-directional relations?

Tags: python, pandas, network-analysis

I have a table which is organized around transactions which may contain the link to one or serveral people.

[image]

My intention is to create a network view for which I need to create bi-directional edges for visualization. Is there a way to organize the table so that it looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

I tried if I could solve the issue by transposing and grouping the table differently. But it doesn't solve my issue of bi-directional relations.

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example and description of your intended output? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

We could use `itertools.combinations` to get unique pairs of `Person` grouped by `Transaction`:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

data = {
    'Transaction': [101,101,101,102,103,103],
    'Person': [1,2,3,3,5,6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pairs = (
    df
    .groupby('Transaction')['Person']
    .apply(lambda gr: pd.DataFrame(combinations(gr, 2), columns=['A','B']))
    .reset_index('Transaction')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
   Transaction  A  B
0          101  1  2
1          101  1  3
2          101  2  3
3          103  5  6
```

Notes:

1. The `data` parameter of [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) can be an iterable object, so we can pass `combinations(...)` to `pd.DataFrame(...)` as is.
2. [GroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) will stack together the output of the same structure into one frame.

Answer (score 0):

Assume dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "txn": [1,1,1,2,3,3],
    "person": ["a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e"],
})
```

Group by transactions to get persons involved in it:

```py
df_grp = df.groupby("txn").agg(person_list=("person", list))

>>     person_list
>> txn            
>> 1     [a, b, c]
>> 2           [c]
>> 3        [d, e]
```

Create pair combinations from person list:

```py
import itertools
df_grp["combinations"] = df_grp.apply(lambda row: list(itertools.combinations(row["person_list"], 2)), axis=1)

>>     person_list              combinations
>> txn                                      
>> 1     [a, b, c]  [(a, b), (a, c), (b, c)]
>> 2           [c]                        []
>> 3        [d, e]                  [(d, e)]
```

Move combinations to individual rows:

```py
df_expl = df_grp[["combinations"]].explode("combinations").dropna().reset_index()

>>    txn combinations
>> 0    1       (a, b)
>> 1    1       (a, c)
>> 2    1       (b, c)
>> 3    3       (d, e)
```

Split person pair to individual columns:

```py
df_expl["A"] = df_expl.apply(lambda row: row["combinations"][0], axis=1)
df_expl["B"] = df_expl.apply(lambda row: row["combinations"][1], axis=1)

>>    txn  A  B
>> 0    1  a  b
>> 1    1  a  c
>> 2    1  b  c
>> 3    3  d  e
```